# What does the fine structure constant describe?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-mechanics

Feynman says in his book "QED" that the square root of the fine structure constant is the probability for a charged particle to emit a photon. But for which wavelength? Or is it an average over all wavelengths?

Note: I meant *virtual* photon, and I meant a stable charged particle, like the electron. One way to rephrase it would be: how many virtual photons (per unit volume) are there in the Coulomb field around an electron?

Comment: You'll have to provide more context. The full quote from the book would be helpful.

Comment: "how many virtual photons are there in the Coulomb field around an electron?"
You know that the coulomb field extends to infinity?

Comment: Feynman wrote "There is a most profound and beautiful question associated with the observed coupling constant, e—the amplitude for a real electron to emit or absorb a real photon. It is a simple number that has been experimentally determined to be close to –0.08542455. (My physicist friends won’t recognize this number, because they like to remember it as the inverse of its square: about 137.03597 with an uncertainty of about 2 in the last decimal place. ...)"

Answer (score 5):

It's neither - or everything. Feynman means that the "vertex in the Feynman diagram" which has 2 external lines corresponding to a charged particle and 1 external line corresponding to a photon (all three particles have any energy/frequency and momentum/inverse_wavelength you want) is proportional to $e\approx \sqrt{\alpha}$. So he really means the probability amplitude.

One needs lots of (or at least several) other calculations to calculate the probability. In particular, a stable charged particle can never emit a photon because it would violate the energy or momentum conservation: in its initial rest frame, the energy is minimized, so one can't afford to increase the energy by changing the state of the motion (plus emitting a photon, which would make the final energy even higher). An unstable particle can decay into another particle and a photon. The decay rate will be proportional to the fine-structure constant (without the square root) but the detailed decay rate depends on the mass of the decaying particle as well as the other final decay product.

Also, $\alpha$ slowly depends on a scale - logarithmically. It's the value at $E=0$, or - approximately - anywhere at masses $m<m_e$ where $m_e$ is the electron mass where $\alpha$ has the familiar value $1/137.03604$. Even though I didn't tell you a particular process that is linked to $\alpha$, it's actually a good idea in the process of "renormalization" to define $\alpha$ operationally exactly as a particular probability or amplitude at particular energies, just like you suggested. However, there are many choices how to do that.

Comment: Ok, so the root of alpha is the probability amplitude. How does this allow to answer the note I added to the question? What is the virtual photon density around an electron?

Comment: Feynman would have loved (½π mod ½)^½/π^π

Comment: Cool formula, pretty accurate

Answer (score 0):

The fine structure constant $\alpha$ describes the fine structure of the Hydrogen levels of energy.

> "I meant a stable charged particle, like the electron."

Is the electron really "stable" if **any** push makes radiation (inelastic "deformation")? I am afraid it is not. Such radiation occurs always ( probability = 1). The "Coulomb center" picture is obtained by summation of all inelastic pictures. It is called an "inclusive" picture. It is not an "elastic" (non-destructive) one.

Answer (score 0):

by Hans de Vries: a numerical elegant approach can be found here:

[The ﬁne structure constant: A radiative series leading to it’s exact value](http://physics-quest.org/fine_structure_constant.pdf)

Vries use both 'pi' and 'e' in the formula and reminds me Feynman (wikipedia - Fine-structure_constant ) '...is it related to pi or perhaps to the base of natural logarithms? ...'
.

I do not know the meaning of this serie.